# Составить регулярное выражение для поиска статуса задания

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Я пытаюсь распарсить логи. У меня есть строка по типу:
"Job ENDED WITH ERROR  at 2021/12/15 19:03:36"
либо
"Job ENDED SUCCESSFUL  at 2021/12/15 19:03:36".

Суть в том, что я хочу получить слова между 'ENDED' и 'at', это будет статус и получить время после 'at', это будет время завершения.
Пишу на языке Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
log = """
Job ENDED WITH ERROR at 2021/12/15 19:03:36
Job ENDED SUCCESSFUL at 2021/12/15 19:03:36
"""
result = re.findall(r"Job\s+ENDED\s+(.+)\s+at\s+(.+)", log)
print(result)
```

Результат:

```
[('WITH ERROR', '2021/12/15 19:03:36'), 
 ('SUCCESSFUL', '2021/12/15 19:03:36')]
```

Comment: Да, отлично, спасибо!